# Newly pushed folder from local repository to Github can't be seen, but the commit history exists

Tags: git, github

I try to practice Github from a Udacity course.

The practice is like a story solitaire.

Below is what I do:

1. Forked a GitHub repository from 
   [here](https://github.com/udacity/create-your-own-adventure) to my GitHub.
2. Clone it from my remote to my local repository.
3. In my working directory, modified walk.md file
4. Create a cliff folder under Chinese/deserthell/walk directory, inside the cliff folder, added a cliff.md file with some text in it
5. cd to chinese/deserthell directory.
6. git add *
7. git commit
8. git push origin ch-desert

During the process everything looked fine.

Except in ch-desert branch on my GitHub, I can't see the cliff folder and the cliff.md files under the  Chinese/deserthell/walk directory.

But, if I check commit history at ch-desert branch, they all exist.

[Link to My Fork](https://github.com/godlike0108/create-your-own-adventure)

Comment: Can you update your post with a link to your github repository?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I've updated!

Comment: That repo has a lot of stuff. You will need to update your question with more details about each step you did. Which files you created, under which branch, commit hashes, status of your local repository, etc.

Comment: Did you put this stuff in a branch? There is a branch called `ch-desert` with 6 commits from the past few hours. Is that what you are looking for? https://github.com/godlike0108/create-your-own-adventure/commits/ch-desert

Comment: @igormilla sorry, I have modified it. If u need additional information just tell me, thanks!

Comment: @DanLowe yes, actually, What i modified is the story under chinese/deserthell , as you can see from commit, there should exist a folder called cliff under folder walk in branch ch-desert, however, in the branch, there are no such cliff, the latest update stay at the third commit, which is I modified the content in the existing walk.md file.

Comment: I have made the question more detailed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a checkout of your repo, and I can see the Cliff directory:

```
igor at im in ~/code/create-your-own-adventure/Chinese/DesertHell/Walk on ch-desert [?] 
$ ls -l 
total 16 
drwxr-xr-x  3 igor  staff  102 Jun 29 10:08 Cliff
-rw-r--r--  1 igor  staff  157 Jun 29 10:08 Walk.md 
drwxr-xr-x  3 igor  staff  102 Jun 29 10:08 test
-rw-r--r--  1 igor  staff  157 Jun 29 10:08 test2.md
```

So it seems that it's something on the github side. I did some extra digging there and found that at different points in time your commits referrer to `DesertHell` directory in a different case:

[fd5312d11213d5aa7c997b9f93de6256cee869a2](https://github.com/godlike0108/create-your-own-adventure/commit/d2e78a1aa7061ef54a0244247d2097210645f182) -> Chinese/deserthell/

[d2e78a1aa7061ef54a0244247d2097210645f182](https://github.com/godlike0108/create-your-own-adventure/commit/fd5312d11213d5aa7c997b9f93de6256cee869a2) ->  Chinese/DesertHell/

Don't know how you managed to use different cases for commiting the same directory. I don't think linux will allow this. But anyway, looks like this is what got github UI super confused.

So when you go to github to:

https://github.com/godlike0108/create-your-own-adventure/tree/ch-desert/Chinese/DesertHell/Walk 
You cannot see your files and directories there.

[image]

But if you change the case of the `DesertHell` to `deserthell`:
https://github.com/godlike0108/create-your-own-adventure/tree/ch-desert/Chinese/deserthell/Walk

[image]

Not sure where you can go from here. You can definitely open a ticket on a github, there is a [Contact github](https://github.com/contact) link right in the bottom of every page. You can link them directly to this question.

But as it's a test repo, I will try to do a second fork, and recreate the same steps you did with the first time, but now put attention to case of directory names you use, and make sure it's persistent.

Comment: Wow! You are definitely right! @igor milla Many thanks for your precise answer and fix my question to make it more clear!

Comment: Glad it solved your issue. It was an interesting puzzle!